# Things to keep in mind while web designing for ie 6 and ie 7

Tags: css

I have just started doing webdesigning I use photoshop and dreamweaver. I have seen that professional websites carry different css for ie 6 and ie 7 and one for all others. Why?
 what are the different things I should keep in mind while designing for internet explorer 6 and 7 and how is it different from designing for other web browsers. Are there any other web browsers that like ie 6 or 7 which require different css ??
can you give a link where i can read more about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basically internet explorer renders websites differently in a bad way. internet explorer 6, 7, 8 all have their little quirks. For the most part other browsers like opera, firefox and safari render sites in a similar fashion.

then main gripe is that internet explorer has a different box model. you can read about common issues with IE here:

http://css-tricks.com/482-ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/

http://haslayout.net/css/

there are however lots of scripts/tools that can help you out:

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/#target-selector

on a side note please don't support ie6, it is by far the worst browser to work with and many companies have stopped supporting it.

Comment: more box-model reading: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200612/internet_explorer_and_the_css_box_model/

Comment: i personally dont support it either but you never know if one day a customer asks me to build a site that supports ie 6 . Thats why i was asking.

Answer (score 2):

I have personally stopped caring about IE6/7 and even glitches in IE8.  I couldn't care less.  But most of my development is either for customers who I make that clear to, or to my non-profit sports/groups that I belong to (free web dev / design).

Its just too much of a hassle to hand hold these older browsers.  Thats where IE6/7 notifiers come in handy (JS that pops up and says "your browser is too old, please update").

Example site:
http://ie6update.com/

Answer (score 0):

Different Style sheets for different browsers is an excellent practice but very expensive.

The main reason is because the CSS version supported by the browsers changes from Browser version to version:
http://www.thescube.com/blog/ie6-vs-ie7-vs-ie8-css-property/

Answer (score 0):

For a quick diagram about what CSS features work in what browser check out http://www.quirksmode.org/. How you then beat every browser in submission is of course a different question all-together…